# Images align horizontal in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

i have use ng repeat to show images and i want them to be in inline formate with rest of all other things i have use in div item.
problem is that what ever i do its not showing in inline.

Item have display block property.
here is the simple and finale html file.

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="countryApp">
<head>
 <script 
src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.26/angular.min.js">
</script>
 <script>
    var countryApp = angular.module('countryApp', []);
  countryApp.controller('CountryCtrl', function ($scope, $http){
    $http.get('countries.json').success(function(data) {
      $scope.countries = data;
    });
  });
</script>

</head>
<body>



      <div ng-controller="CountryCtrl" >

         <div class="item">
                <div ng-repeat="country in countries" class="w3l-movie-gride-agile w3l-movie-gride-agile1 owl-item">
                            <a href="single.php?myNumber={{country.vid}}" class="hvr-shutter-out-horizontal"><img ng-src="thumbnail/{{country.flagURL}}" title="album-name" class="img-responsive" alt=" ">
                                <div class="w3l-action-icon"><i class="fa fa-play-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
                            </a>

                            <div class="mid-1 agileits_w3layouts_mid_1_home">
                                <div class="w3l-movie-text">
                                    <h6><a href="single.html">Citizen Soldier</a></h6>                          
                                </div>

                            <div class="mid-2 agile_mid_2_home">
                                <p>2016</p>
                                <div class="block-stars">
                                    <ul class="w3l-ratings">
                                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-star-half-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                            </div>
                            </div>


                        <div class="ribben">
                            <p>NEW</p>
                        </div>
                </div>

        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It is a `CSS` issue, please attach Final HTML to play with.

Comment: its not an css issue beacuse the one which dont have angular js is working properly align horizontal

Comment: here i have edit and simplified the code

Answer (score 1):

The element you put `ng-repeat` on is also repeatet. So each iteration is wrapped in a regular `<div>`. So unless you have some global styling that applies to all `<div>` elements, it wouldn't inline.

To fix it you basically just have to move the `ng-repeat`-directive a level down. Like this:

```
<div class="item">
    <div ng-repeat="country in countries" 
         class="w3l-movie-gride-agile w3l-movie-gride-agile1">

        // ... rest of content

    </div>
</div>
```

I reckon that should do it.

Comment: sry vertical i want it to be horizontal

Comment: Could you try to reproduce the issue in a Plunker or similar?

Comment: i have not use plunker

Comment: I'm asking you if you will create a Plunker (or something similar) that repreduces the issue. Right now there's not enough information to help you. Seeing the issue "in action" would make it easier.

Comment: how to make Plunker please let me know or give a link

Comment: Open https://plnkr.co/. Launch editor. Create new AngularJS 1.5 plunker. Recreate your issue in the code. Save and post the link to it here.